# Setting window status bar color when popup window is displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

Is there a way to set the window status bar color when a popup window is displayed? I have tried using

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.setStatusBarColor(color);
```

But this does not seem to work on Lollipop

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this for days, it seems to be a bug in API 21 that was fixed in API 22

To get around it I created a PopupWindow but instead of using `MATCH_PARENT` as height, I calculated the height of the screen and substracted the height of the status bar size. Using this, the popup window shows with the status bar color of the underlying activity

Here's what I used

```
private void showPopup(View popupView){
    popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, getPopupHeight(), false);
    popup.showAtLocation(getView(), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
}

private int getPopupHeight() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        int statusBarHeight = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return size.y - statusBarHeight;
    } else {
        return ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps someone else that might struggle with this

Comment: PlusOne `Gravity.NO_GRAVITY` can be replaced with `Gravity.BOTTOM`.

Comment: I observe the same issue in Android 4.4 currently. So changing condition to `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {` fixed my problem